# Is Sunset Sarsaparilla food?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, achievements

Specifically regarding the Desert Survivalist achievement (trophy in PS3 parlance): Does Sunset Sarsaparilla count as food toward the requirement to "heal 10,000 points of damage with food?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

Neither Sunset Sarsaparilla nor Nuka-Cola count towards this achievement.

Comment: Dangit, I was afraid of that ... I assume water is out too, then, right?

Comment: Yes. Water is also out. [The wiki has some good tips.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_Survivalist)